# Flux React gulp

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux, reactjs-flux

Trying to create a Flux store.  When I run gulp and check my index.html I get an error "Uncaught TypeError: listener must be a function"

```
var AppDispatcher = require('../dispatchers/app-dispatcher');
var AppConstants = require('../constants/app-constants');
var assign = require('object-assign'); 
var EventEmitterProto = require('events').EventEmitter.prototype;
var CHANGE_EVENT = 'CHANGE'; //broadcast this everytime there is a change

var _catalog = [];
var _cartItems = [];

var AppStore = assign(EventEmitterProto, {
    emitChange: function(){
    this.emit(CHANGE_EVENT)
},
addChangeListener: function(callback){
    this.on(CHANGE_EVENT, callback); //<---if I comment this out code runs perfect
},
removeChangeListener: function(callback){
    this.removeListener(CHANGE_EVENT, callback)
},
getCart: function(){
    return _cartItems
},
getCatalog: function(){
    return _catalog
},
getCartTotals: function(){
    return _cartTotals()
}

});
module.exports = AppStore;
```

Below is the only component with a listener

```
var React = require('react');
var AppStore = require('../stores/app-store.js');
var RemoveFromCart = require('./app-removefromcart.js'); //this is a component
var Increase = require('./app-increaseitem'); //this is a component
var Decrease = require('./app-decreaseitem'); //this is a component

function cartItems(){
    return {items: AppStore.getCart()}
}

var Catalog = React.createClass({
    getInitialState:function(){
        return cartItems();
    },
    componentWillMount: function(){
        AppStore.addChangeListener(this.onChange)
},
_onChange: function(){
    this.setState(cartItems());
},
render: function(){
    var total = 0;
    var items = this.state.items.map(function(item, i){
        var subtotal = item.cost * item.qty;
        total += subtotal;
            return (
                <tr key={i}>
                    <td><RemoveFromCart /></td>
                    <td>{item.title}</td>
                    <td>{item.qty}</td>
                    <td>
                        <Increase index={i} />
                        <Decrease index={i} />
                    </td>
                    <td>${subtotal}</td>
                </tr>
                );
        })//end map

    return (
        <table className="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Item</th>
                <th>Qty</th>
                <th></th>
                <th>Subtotal</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {items}
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td colSpan="4" className="text-right">Total</td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
        );
}
});

module.exports = Catalog;
```

Please help. This is really hurting my head

Comment: Do you have a typo in your component?   You're referencing `this.onChange` but the actual function in the component is called `_onChange`

Answer (score 1):

you might need to change

```
AppStore.addChangeListener(this._onChange)
```

logic to componentDidMount function like

```
   componentDidMount:function(){
      AppStore.addChangeListener(this._onChange)
    }
```